# ng-hide button if name matches in second object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hi I'm having two objects one for showing list in table

```
 $scope.data=[
    {"id" : "1","name" : "item1"},
    {"id" : "2","name" : "item2"},
    {"id" : "4","name" : "item4"},
    {"id" : "7","name" : "item7"},
    {"id" : "8","name" : "item8"},
    {"id" : "9","name" : "item9"},
    ]
```

where the object consists of list of item names as follows

```
 $scope.items=[
          {id:"1",itemName:"item1"},
          {id:"2",itemName:"item5"},
        ]
```

In table i'm displaying data in first object along with button in each tr.Now i need to hide button in tr if that item name exists in second object.

```js
var c = angular.module('myApp',[])
c.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
  
  $scope.data=[
    {"id" : "1","name" : "item1"},
    {"id" : "2","name" : "item2"},
    {"id" : "4","name" : "item4"},
    {"id" : "7","name" : "item7"},
    {"id" : "8","name" : "item8"},
    {"id" : "9","name" : "item9"},
    ]  
  $scope.items=[
      {id:"1",itemName:"item1"},
      {id:"2",itemName:"item5"},
    ]
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

   <table border="2">
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Action</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
        <td>{{row.name}}</td>
        <td>
          <button type="submit">Edit</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>


  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an another array like this, to hold the values of itemName

```
$scope.values = $scope.items.map(i => i.itemName);
```

And in you template, use it like,

```
ng-hide="values.indexOf(row.name) > -1"
```

```js
var c = angular.module('myApp',[])
c.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
  
  $scope.data=[
    {"id" : "1","name" : "item1"},
    {"id" : "2","name" : "item2"},
    {"id" : "4","name" : "item4"},
    {"id" : "7","name" : "item7"},
    {"id" : "8","name" : "item8"},
    {"id" : "9","name" : "item9"},
    ]  
  $scope.items=[
      {id:"1",itemName:"item1"},
      {id:"2",itemName:"item5"},
    ];
   $scope.values = $scope.items.map(i => i.itemName);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

   <table border="2">
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Action</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
        <td>{{row.name}}</td>
        <td>
          <button ng-hide="values.indexOf(row.name) > -1" type="submit">Edit</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>


  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use something like this in html button

```
<button type="submit" ng-if="checkIfExists(row.id)">Edit</button>
```

in your constroller add function

```
$scope.checkIfExists = (id) => $scope.items.map(elem=>elem.id).includes(id);
```

```js
var c = angular.module('myApp',[])
c.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
  
  $scope.data=[
    {"id" : "1","name" : "item1"},
    {"id" : "2","name" : "item2"},
    {"id" : "4","name" : "item4"},
    {"id" : "7","name" : "item7"},
    {"id" : "8","name" : "item8"},
    {"id" : "9","name" : "item9"},
    ]  
  $scope.items=[
      {id:"1",itemName:"item1"},
      {id:"2",itemName:"item5"},
    ];
    
    $scope.checkIfExists = (id) => $scope.items.map(elem=>elem.id).includes(id);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

   <table border="2">
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Action</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
        <td>{{row.name}}</td>
        <td>
          <button type="submit" ng-if="checkIfExists(row.id)">Edit</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>


  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution could be made a lot simpler by using a helper library such as `underscore` or `lodash`, but this should work:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.data=[
    {"id" : "1","name" : "item1"},
    {"id" : "2","name" : "item2"},
    {"id" : "4","name" : "item4"},
    {"id" : "7","name" : "item7"},
    {"id" : "8","name" : "item8"},
    {"id" : "9","name" : "item9"},
  ];  
  $scope.items=[
      {id:"1",itemName:"item1"},
      {id:"2",itemName:"item5"},
  ];
  $scope.itemExists = function(name) {
    var exists = false;
    $scope.items.forEach(function(elem) {
      if (elem.itemName === name) {
        exists = true;
      }
    }));
    return exists;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

   <table border="2">
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Action</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
        <td>{{row.name}}</td>
        <td>
          <button ng-hide="itemExists(row.name)" type="submit">Edit</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>


  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `find` method of JavaScript arrays (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_find.asp) in a `ng-show` directive to accomplish this:

```js
var c = angular.module('myApp',[])
c.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){

  $scope.containsItem = function(item){
      return item.itemName == this;
  };
  
  $scope.data=[
    {"id" : "1","name" : "item1"},
    {"id" : "2","name" : "item2"},
    {"id" : "4","name" : "item4"},
    {"id" : "7","name" : "item7"},
    {"id" : "8","name" : "item8"},
    {"id" : "9","name" : "item9"},
    ]  
  $scope.items=[
      {id:"1",itemName:"item1"},
      {id:"2",itemName:"item5"},
    ]
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

   <table border="2">
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Action</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
        <td>{{row.name}}</td>
        <td>
          <button type="submit" ng-show="items.find(containsItem, row.name)">Edit</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>


  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array and add a new key to this object like `showButton`, the value of which will be true or false depending on the item present in both array

```js
var c = angular.module('myApp', [])
c.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.data = [{
      "id": "1",
      "name": "item1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "item2"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "item4"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "name": "item7"
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "name": "item8"
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "name": "item9"
    },
  ]
  $scope.items = [{
      id: "1",
      itemName: "item1"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      itemName: "item5"
    },
  ]

  $scope.updatedData = $scope.data.map(function(item) {
    var findIndex = $scope.items.findIndex(function(secItem) {
      return item.id === secItem.id
    });
    if (findIndex === -1) {
      return {
        "id": item.id,
        "name": item.name,
        "showButton": true
      }

    } else {
      return {
        "id": item.id,
        "name": item.name,
        "showButton": false
      }

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

  <table border="2">
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in updatedData">
      <td>{{row.name}}</td>
      <td>
        <button ng-if="row.showButton" type="submit">Edit</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>


</body>
```